# Laravel query builder with pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have two tables with a pivot table

## Table `tours`

`id | name | country_id | featured`

## Table `countries`

`id | name`

## Pivot Table `country_tour`

`id | country_id | tour_id`

I want to to find the tour that has `featured` column of tours table set to 1 and `country_id` of `country_tour` table set to 1.

Comment: what you try provide.

Comment: Does your relation looks like this - `Country has many tours` and `Tour has many Countries` ??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

You can do it like this using Laravel's query Builder method - [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas):

Your models should look like this (Many to Many Relationships):

Tour Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tour extends Model
{
    public function countries() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country');
    }
}
```

and Country Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
    public function tours() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tour');
    }
}
```

and now you can fetch the desired results by using the below query:

```
Tour::where('featured', 1)
    ->whereHas('countries', function($q) {
        $q->where('id', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

This will get you the collection of tours with `featured = 1` and having `country with id = 1`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks mate for quick response. The code ran without errors after few tweks i changed id to country_id in function as it was throwing error. But the code didn't fetched any data from db.

Comment: And i also changes countries to country as the name of my method is country.

Comment: Does your relation looks like this - `Country has many tours` and `Tour has many Countries` ??

Comment: i have pasted my codes above and  please have a loook at my question again.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to Saumya Rastogi answer, change the id to countries.id to avoid "column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous" error.

i.e.

From:

```
Tour::where('featured', 1)
->whereHas('countries', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', 1);
})->get()
```

To:

```
Tour::where('featured', 1)
->whereHas('countries', function($q) {
    $q->where('countries.id', 1);
})->get();
```